# Find the value of $p$ and $q$ of the quadratic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The quadratic equation $x^2+px+q=0$ has roots $-2$ and $6$. Find the value of $p$ and $q$.

Do I have to make two equations?

Something like this?

When $x=-2$, (real and distinct roots) $b^2-4ac>0$

$(-2)^2+p(-2)+q>0$

Making an equation: $q>-4+2p$ ---------------(1)

Then $x=6$....Should it be something like this or any different method?

Comment: $$-p=-2+6, q=-2\cdot6$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee you are right, but how does that come?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Viete's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas):  the roots of $\;ax^2+bx+c=0\;,\;\;a\neq 0\;$ , are $\;\alpha\,,\,\beta\;$ iff

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$

and from here

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\alpha+\beta=-\frac ba\\(2)&\;\;\;\;\;\;\alpha\beta=\frac ca\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is useful to remember the following: writing your quadratic equation $$x^2-Sx+P=0$$ you have that $S$ is the sum (resp $P$ the product) of the two roots.

Here, you get $p=-(-2+6)=-4$, $q=-2\cdot 6=-12$.

Answer (score 0):

What are the roots of $(x+2)(x-6)=0$? How does that relate to your problem?